# I finished Weyworld but where is Hubworld?

Tags: godus

I finished unlocking all of the beacons in Weyworld. There is no option to do anything else.

I read that there is also hubworld but how do I get there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like hub world was canceled and never fully released per this discussion on their main forum board - http://godus.boards.net/thread/724/where-hubworld

Comment: Dead link, archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20150510064747/http://godus.boards.net/thread/724/where-hubworld .